# How is OAuth2 / OIDC used in basic protection of backend API using AWS API Gateway and Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I have the following architechture for my React SPA web app in AWS:

[image]

For Frontend:

I am using Cloudfront + S3 bucket to host a React App frontend.
Users who visits the url `https://www.myapp.com` will be visiting this cloudfront and thus loading the react app frontend code in their browser.

For Backend API calls:

All requests to the backend APIs domain (https://www.api.myapp.com/*) are directed to an AWS API Gateway.
The API Gateway is configured to use a cognito user pool as authorizer. The request must contain the correct token to be verified by AWS Cognito.
On successful validation, a request is then forwarded to an EC2-instance running nodejs Express app, which is the backend for my web app.

How Authentication is done:

Any user who puts the url `https://www.myapp.com` in his browser will get the full frontend ReactJS code loaded in the browser, no authentication required. However, The frontend code will do a simple check:

- If the user has not logged in, it will only show the login page;
- If the user has logged in (meaning that valid tokens do exist in local storage), it will show the dashboard page, and start making HTTP requests to backend ( `https://www.api.myapp.com/*` ) to fetch user data.

We use `aws-amplify` to perform login task. Here is the root `App.js` file :

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import {
  setStoredAuthToken,
  setStoredAccessToken,
  getStoredAuthToken,
} from 'shared/utils/authToken';
import LoginPage from 'pages/LoginPage';
import Dashboard from 'pages/Dashboard';

const AppCustomSignIn = () => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState('NotChecked');
  const [userGroups, setUserGroups] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then(function (result) {
        setCurrentUser(result);
        const groups =
          result.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload['cognito:groups'];
        setUserGroups(groups);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setCurrentUser('NotSignedIn');
      });
  }, []);

  if (currentUser === 'NotSignedIn') {
    return (
        <div>
          <LoginPage />
        </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dashboard currentUser={currentUser} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default AppCustomSignIn;
```

And the `<LoginPage />` component contains the following code to use `aws-amplify` to login:

```
const user = await Auth.signIn(formData.username, formData.password);
...
```

Note that we have configured the AWS-Amplify this way:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_REGION,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    storage: browserStorage,
    authenticationFlowType: 'CUSTOM_AUTH',
  },
});
```

We have provided both the Cognito user pool ID and the App client ID.

Questions:

Is this setup using OIDC to do authentication? I understand the typical workflow of OAuth 2.0 and OIDC, but this one above does not look like it. There are a few doubts:

In cognito user pool and in the registered app client, I have the following config:

```
OAuth grant types: Authorization code grant

OpenID Connect scopes:
aws.cognito.signin.user.admin
email
openid
profile
```

In Authorization code grant in OAuth 2.0 / OIDC, a code and a redirect URI are returned by the Auth server to the browser. The browser then send request to the redirect URI with the code included. And then in the back channel, the client app server takes the code to the auth server and exchanges for the actual access token and ID token. The tokens are not sent back the user's browser for storage.

However, in my case:

- there is no such client app code that does the exchanging code for tokens step.
- the browser receives tokens after calling `AWS-Amplify`'s `Auth.signIn(formData.username, formData.password);` and stores them in local storage.
- AWS Cognito verifies tokens on the requests sent to API Gateway, and determines whether the call is authoized.

Am I using OIDC or not? In OAuth 2.0 / OIDC, we have the "Auth server" and the "client".

In the AWS Congito, I think that the user pool is the "Auth server" , and the client app registered in the user pool is the "client". However, this "client" is not controlled by me; e.g. I don't write code for it to exchange authorization code for access token with the user pool (Auth server).

What am I doing then in this design pattern?

What are the disadvantages and vulnerabilities and wrong-doings in my setting?

By the way, I found this blog, which is almost exactly what I am doing:
https://awskarthik82.medium.com/part-1-securing-aws-api-gateway-using-aws-cognito-oauth2-scopes-410e7fb4a4c0

https://awskarthik82.medium.com/part-2-securing-aws-api-gateway-using-aws-cognito-oauth2-scopes-and-openid-connect-f20fd1392e97

[image]